# Unmarshalling vaule field of json to already existing constant

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have constants defined as below

```
const (
    temp  = "metadata+"
    temp2 = "field2"
)
```

and structure defined as

```
type TransformationInfo struct {
    SourceField string
    DestField   string
}
```

when I call Unmarshal like below, I want if temp field (or rather any constant if defined with string value) to be replaced with its variable

```
transformationInfo := new(TransformationInfo)
js := `{"SourceField ": "temp", "DestField": "temp2"}`
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), transformationInfo )
fmt.Printf("transformationInfo : %v\n", transformationInfo)
```

This needs to output:
transformationInfo : &{metadata+ field2}
instead of
transformationInfo : &{temp temp2}

Comment: There is no magic incantation that will do it for you. You have to do it yourself. One thing you could do to _somewhat_ automatize it is to define a custom string type that implements the unmarshaler interface and looks at each incoming data slice, and if that data matches a known constant's name, use that constant's value instead of the data itself.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code in the question. What problems did you encounter?